# How to create json object and push array with key/ value pair in angular 4

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I want to push some images array to json object with key/value pair.
but I am confuse I create a Json object and then push array with key/value pair.
here I am pushing these images in slideimages array now i want to create a json object of image array. I have code like below :-

```
if(element.optioinimages){ var slideimages = []; element.optionimages.forEach((element,) =>{ slideimages.push({image:URL+element[0]}); consol.log(slideimages) }
```

after that I want to create json object and then want to push array of images in that.
Where to declare json object and how to push array in that  object.
these images want to push in json object

```
0: {image: "http://35.225.229.210:8087//SurveyImages/1550920004837image.PNG"} 1: {image: "http://35.225.229.210:8087//SurveyImages/1550920005389image.PNG"} 2: {image: "http://35.225.229.210:8087//SurveyImages/1550920005954image.PNG"} 3: {image: "http://35.225.229.210:8087//SurveyImages/1550920005957image.PNG"} 4: {image: "http://35.225.229.210:8087//SurveyImages/1550920006239image.PNG"} 5: {image: "http://35.225.229.210:8087//SurveyImages/1550897466703image.PNG"}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you just want to add an array of images in json object?

Comment: yes but also i want display in view page

Comment: please state your problem briefly what is your input data and required output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, initialise your variable as an Object, keep `sliderImages` as inner Array.

```
var obj = {sliderImages: []};
```

Then push into **obj.sliderImages** , as below

```
obj.sliderImages.push({image:URL+element[0]});
```

Here is the full code,

```
if (element.optioinimages) {
  var obj = {sliderImages: []};
  element.optionimages.forEach((element) => {
    obj.sliderImages.push({ image: URL + element[0] });
    console.log(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , so you mean we are pushing  images in obj

Comment: No, pushing into the array which is inside result object.

Comment: `if(element.optioinimages){ var slideimages = []; element.optionimages.forEach((element,) =>{ slideimages.push({image:URL+element[0]}); consol.log(slideimages) }`

Comment: Do I need to write it after above code or need to correction in existing code.

Comment: Need to correct the existing code. I have edited the answer please check.

Comment: `Object
sliderImages: Array(5)
0: {image: "http://35.225.229.210:8087//SurveyImages/1550920004837image.PNG"}
1: {image: "http://35.225.229.210:8087//SurveyImages/1550920005389image.PNG"}
2: {image: "http://35.225.229.210:8087//SurveyImages/1550920005954image.PNG"}
3: {image: "http://35.225.229.210:8087//SurveyImages/1550920005957image.PNG"}
4: {image: "http://35.225.229.210:8087//SurveyImages/1550920006239image.PNG"}`

Comment: it is looking like above

Comment: Can you give me an example of your desired output? If you just want key - value pair, you don't need to use array at all. Just object is enough. But your question is confusing a bit.

Comment: Actually, it is bit hard to explain for me.so 
Please can I have your skype id so that  I can explain.
your help would be appreciated

Comment: I have to show these images in slideshow only where the user uploaded multiple images. and for that I have made condition in view page `<span *ngIf = "survey.optionimage  && survey.optionimage.length >1">
          
            <ngx-slides [slideImages]="slideImages" [config]="config"></ngx-slides>
            </span>`
but what happened here all  optionimages are showing at one time but what I want to if  A user uploaded 4 images show in that section only 4 images should display and if B user uploaded 2 images  then two images should show in that particular user section.

Comment: but these  images which have upload by A  & B user are showing  A & B section not showing as per the they uploaded.

Comment: Please suggest me , I will wait for your reply.

Comment: @santosh Hi are you there ?

Comment: @santosh Can you please help with how can I key/ value-pair

Comment: and Please I have to display in HTML page.

Comment: `NewElement: any = [];`

I am doing like this `this.NewElement = obj;`

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga Sorry man, I was busy and just totally forgot about this conversation. Have you got solution?

Comment: @santosh Not so far, still I am striving

Comment: @KuldeepKoranga As per my understanding on your problem, first you have to group the images based on the user. I assume, you will have a ngx-slides section for each user. To understand the problem in detail, can you please create https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fstczd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html and share me the link to reproduce the issue? So I will solve the problem directly there.

Comment: Can you [please take my pc on remotely ?

Comment: Actually,I have been stucking for long time, so your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @SantoshV Are you there ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, soon I will ping you.